# Where to specify Amazon S3 bucket directory name to upload file

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS low level API to upload file to S3 bucket from .net application.

```
InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = keyName
};

UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = keyName,
    UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
    PartNumber = i,
    PartSize = partSize,
    FilePosition = filePosition,
    FilePath = filePath,
};
```

Here i specify bucket name but where do i specify directory name within bucket to upload file.
eg: 
Bucket name: SampleBucket

File to be uploaded to folder: Upload/JSON

So here, i need to upload file to JSON folder which is within Upload directory.

Where do i specify this path?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken you store things based on the key attribute ( so in this case you'd probably use the key Upload/JSON/<filename> ) [ more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html ]

Comment: or... in this case, there is an example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html

Comment: Yes, assigning folder(Upload/JSON/<filename>) to Key worked perfectly!